# invalid literal for int() with base 10: '

Tags: django, python-2.7, sentry, raven, django-logging

I recently added sentry for error tracking in my project and configure raven according to documentation [here](https://docs.sentry.io/clients/python/integrations/django/) but getting the error shown below.

### settings.py

```
import raven


INSTALLED_APPS = [    
    # 3rd party app
    'raven.contrib.django.raven_compat',
]    

RAVEN_CONFIG = {
    'dsn': 'https://*****@sentry.io/224093',
    'release': raven.fetch_git_sha(os.path.dirname(os.pardir)),
}
```

### Error Log

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
October 02, 2017 - 11:31:58
Django version 1.10, using settings 'FoodCham.settings.development'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Sending message of length 2240 to https://sentry.io/api/224093/store/
Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 244, in _legacy_get_response
    response = middleware_method(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/raven/contrib/django/middleware/__init__.py", line 135, in process_request
    request.body  # forces stream to be read into memory
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/http/request.py", line 267, in body
    int(self.META.get('CONTENT_LENGTH', 0)) > settings.DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE):
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 244, in _legacy_get_response
    response = middleware_method(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/raven/contrib/django/middleware/__init__.py", line 135, in process_request
    request.body  # forces stream to be read into memory
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/http/request.py", line 267, in body
    int(self.META.get('CONTENT_LENGTH', 0)) > settings.DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE):
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
[02/Oct/2017 11:32:04] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 69274
```

Any helpful answer will be appreciated!

Comment: What is your `CONTENT_LENGTH` setting? It shouldn't be empty.

Comment: Try setting the default to `'0'` instead of simply `0`

Comment: @The_Cthulhu_Kid I can't change framework settings

Comment: `self.META.get('CONTENT_LENGTH')` is sent `""` by the server. You should update the server's settings to have it send the content length as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug in Django not in raven which is solved in [Django 1.10.8](https://github.com/django/django/commit/5c63b3e5a797102d915e1683971517f747a28013), by just upgrading django-1.10 to django-1.10.8 it works fine.

Answer (score 5):

It's a [bug with a Django version](https://github.com/getsentry/raven-python/issues/1099). I had Django 1.10 installed and was seeing this error. Upgrading to 1.10.8 as mentioned in the issue solved the problem.